# Regarding projective manifolds with decomposable real tangent bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex projective manifold. Suppose its real tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{R}}X$ splits as a direct sum of two sub-bundles of even rank. Does this give any useful information about the manifold $X$ (e.g. its Euler characteristic, etc.)?

I apologize for being somewhat vague about my question. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: What is the degree of a vector bundle (real or complex)?

Comment: @abx : I'm extremely sorry... I meant rank. I've edited the question.

Comment: It doesn't tell you anything about the Euler characteristic. What other kind of useful information were you hoping for?